# PhoneGap SELECT JOIN ON WHERE qty >0

Tags: sqlite, cordova

I have looked at many examples and have tried this many different ways for the past several hours and I just can't get it to work. I want to get only orderItems where the quantity is not 0. What I actually get is all orderItems even if the qty is 0. I found a good example that I modeled my latest attempt after with no luck.

Here is my latest attempt:

```
tx.executeSql('SELECT orders.Id, orders.name, orderItems.itemNum, orderItems.desc, orderItems.qty FROM orders JOIN orderItems ON (orders.Id = orderItems.orderID) WHERE orderItems.qty > 0', [], getOrdersSuccess, errorCB);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#comparisons) says:

> An INTEGER or REAL value is less than any TEXT value.

Ensure that your `qty` values are numbers, not strings.

Comment: I double checked my code just to make sure but all values inserted or updated into qty are numbers.

Comment: You got it! I didn't realize that $('#inputID').val() returned numbers as strings. I ended up using qty =  parseInt($('#inputID').val())